# React-Redux: Clean the state

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my app I do two related gets. From the first get I get all the ids, when one of these ids is chosen, it is used to make a new api call that gives me back some data.

So after the first get I have a situation like:

```
docent:  (2) [{…}, {…}]
          0: {id: "12", name: "Name1", surname: "Surname1"}
          1: {id: "13", name: "Name2", surname: "Surname2"}
          length: 2__proto__: Array(0)

agenda:  []
```

after the user chooses one of the ids, the agenda array is also populated with the information retrieved according to that id like:

```
agenda:   (2) [{…}, {…}]
          0: {id: "1", docent_id: "12", date: "2020-05-27", start_at: "09:00:00", end_at: "10:00:00"}
          1: {id: "2", docent_id: "12", date: "2020-05-27", start_at: "10:00:00", end_at: "11:00:00"}
          length: 2
```

My problem is that: 
If the user changes the id of the **docent** array again, the **agenda** array becomes:

```
agenda:  (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
         0: {id: "1", docent_id: "12", date: "2020-05-27", start_at: "09:00:00", end_at: "10:00:00"}
         1: {id: "2", docent_id: "12", date: "2020-05-27", start_at: "10:00:00", end_at: "11:00:00"}
         2: {id: "3", docent_id: "13", date: "2020-05-28", start_at: "09:00:00", end_at: "10:00:00"}
         length: 3
```

So I have the past informations plus the new information.

I would like to be able to delete the information saved in the agenda in case the user changes the docent's ID. How can I do?

Actions:

```
export const agendaList = (id, agenda) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        fetch(api + id, {
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
            },
        })
            .then((result) => result.json())
            .then((agenda) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: "AGENDA_LIST",
                    agenda: agenda
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log("An error occurred.", error));
    };
```

Reducers:

```
const initialState = {
agenda: []
}
export const reducer = (state = initialState , action) => {
case 'AGENDA_LIST':
            return {...state, agenda: [...state.agenda, ...action.agenda]};
        default: 
            return state;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your reducer is **merging** the current state and the action data:

```
return {...state, agenda: [...state.agenda, ...action.agenda]};
```

You want to **replace** the current state agenda:

```
return {
  ...state,
  agenda: action.agenda
};
```

Comment: Oh! But in this way is printend only the first one result of agenda